# How can I change twitter web intent message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter

I am using twitter web intent to share on twitter. Initially I am doing like this

Example

> https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.sourabhsomani.com&text=Hey%20This%20is%20my%20website&via=sourabh_somani

and the output looks like as follows:
[image]

But What I want, I want to place my text just after the URL, How can I do like that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But What I want, I want to place my text just after the URL, How can I do like that.

You can just leave out the `url` parameter, and put the URL into the `text` as well:

https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sourabhsomani.com+Hey+This+is+my+website&via=sourabh_somani

Comment: Thanks this is nice

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

Urlencode your custom text and then append it to the url get variable `text`

```
var text ="Costom text";
var url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.sourabhsomani.com&text='+encodeURIComponent(text)+'&via=sourabh_somani';
```

```js
var text ="Costom text";
var url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.sourabhsomani.com&text='+encodeURIComponent(text)+'&via=sourabh_somani';
$('a').attr('href',url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.sourabhsomani.com&text=Hey%20This%20is%20my%20website&via=sourabh_somani">tweet</a>
```

Comment: i don't know any **Sorry Not working** error in javascript